# EMC storage - set login/password VIA naviseccli command

Tags: storage, solaris, emc

I have two NETRA machines that connected to EMC storage ( EMC flare 28 )

I installed Solaris 10 on both NETRA machines

my question - is it possible to set the login and password  for EMC storage by:

```
      /opt/Navisphere/bin/naviseccli command
```

.

I want to run naviseccli command from solrais machines in order to set the login and password for EMC storage , but I don't sure if it possible

remark - I cant set the login/password from http//192.9.100.4 ( WEB explorer )

example - when I try from my solaris machine to get info from EMC PORT SP-A

```
     /opt/Navisphere/bin/naviseccli -Address 192.9.100.4 ( 192.9.100.4 is SP A EMC port )
```

.

```
      Error returned from the Management Server on 192.9.100.4
      Authentication failed. Possible reasons for failure are invalid security file, invalid username, password and/or scope.
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to set the password from the Navisphere client, but I've always just done it through the command line. Just SSH into the management port of the control center, and use the passwd command.

Comment: please give me example for that , which syntax from the solaris ( command line  ) need to type ?

Comment: Assuming the IP address for your control station is 192.168.100.105, you would type ssh nasadmin@192.168.100.105, authenticate, and then at the command prompt, type passwd.

Comment: sorry but not clearly for me about hasadmin - why hasadmin , anyway when I perfrom ssh to nasadmin@192.168.100.105, I get connection refused

Comment: then it's probably your network or ssh saved keys or something.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this procedure

/opt/Navisphere/bin/naviseccli -Address 192.9.100.4 -user &&& -password ^^^^ -scope 0 faults -list